# Filter by ranges supplied by two vectors, without a join operation

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, subset

I wish to do exactly this: [Take dates from one dataframe and filter data in another dataframe - R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36190921/take-dates-from-one-dataframe-and-filter-data-in-another-dataframe-r)

except without joining, as I am afraid that after I join my data the result will be too big to fit in memory, prior to the filter.

Here is sample data:

```
tmp_df <- data.frame(a = 1:10)
```

I wish to do an operation that looks like this:

```
lower_bound <- c(2, 4)
upper_bound <- c(2, 5)
tmp_df %>%
    filter(a >= lower_bound & a <= upper_bound) # does not work as <= is vectorised inappropriately
```

and my desired result is:

```
> tmp_df[(tmp_df$a <= 2 & tmp_df$a >= 2) | (tmp_df$a <= 5 & tmp_df$a >= 4), , drop = F] 
# one way to get indices to subset data frame, impractical for a long range vector
  a
2 2
4 4
5 5
```

My problem with memory requirements (with respect to the join solution linked) is when `tmp_df` has many more rows and the `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` vectors have many more entries. A `dplyr` solution, or a solution that can be part of pipe is preferred.

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454565/efficient-way-to-filter-one-data-frame-by-ranges-in-another/

Comment: You could simply do `tmp_df %>% filter(a == 2 | between(a, 4, 5))` or combine a few `between` statements, or you could simply use the same syntax as in base R such as `tmp_df %>% filter(a == 2 | (a <= 5 & a >= 4))` or even `tmp_df %>% filter(a %in% c(2, 4:5))`. I really fail to understand what's the question's about even.

Comment: The question is about how you do this when the vectors supplying the ranges have lots of elements, say 100 each.

Comment: As always, you are answering comments without using @ (so I won't see your further comments), but I suggest you clarify that in your question and show a real use case rather just a small example which could be easily solved in many simple ways.

Comment: I have reworded the question which hopefully addresses your comments regarding the clarity. I do not believe in real use cases when simple examples are easier to read and understand.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Why am I not using `@`? Plainly because I did not know how the comment notification system works: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125208/when-exactly-do-i-get-comment-notifications.  I assumed incorrectly that stackoverflow notifies everyone in this comment thread. Thanks, I have fixed the typo  you noticed in the bounds. I will investigate `data.table::between`, but I think `inrange` is the function I want.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, `between` works against same length vectors, so `%inrange%` would be better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you could borrow the `inrange` function from `data.table`, which

> checks whether each value in x is in between any of the
>   intervals provided in lower,upper.

Usage:

*inrange(x, lower, upper, incbounds=TRUE)*

```
library(dplyr); library(data.table)

tmp_df %>% filter(inrange(a, c(2,4), c(2,5)))
#  a
#1 2
#2 4
#3 5
```

Comment: Great solution ````

Comment: @Wen Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Very neat, although I note that in the helpfile it says `inrange makes use of this functionality and performs a range join`. I have to check that this does not cause memory requirements to blow up.

Comment: @Alex, it was precisely implemented by having memory requirements in mind. I'd love to know how it turned up on your original dataset.

Comment: @arun I am doing a 4 million row by 30 million row range join (since `inrange` uses non equi-joins I decided to rewrite everything using `data.table` syntax) and it is easily staying in memory.

Comment: @Alex, very happy. Thanks for getting back to me.

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like to stick with `dplyr` it has similar functionality provided through the `between` function.

```
# ranges I want to check between
my_ranges <- list(c(2,2), c(4,5), c(6,7))

tmp_df <- data.frame(a=1:10)
tmp_df %>% 
  filter(apply(bind_rows(lapply(my_ranges, 
                                FUN=function(x, a){
                                  data.frame(t(between(a, x[1], x[2])))
                                  }, a)
                         ), 2, any))
  a
1 2
2 4
3 5
4 6
5 7
```

Just be aware that the argument boundaries are included by default and that cannot be changed as with `inrange`

Comment: thanks for this, the problem is that I do not know how to, and is possible inefficient, to expand each vector into individual OR statements to give the required filtration

Comment: Have you considered keeping your ranges in a list, then using other functions that do the expansion for you? I've edited my answer to be more like this case, although, it makes the code less readable. I'm sure there's a cleaner way to write the code, it's just not coming to me right now.